# Is it required to make a custom manger for a custom user model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers, django-custom-user, django-custom-manager

I am making a custom user model using the `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin` by following these two tutorials ([tutorial-1](http://blackglasses.me/2013/09/17/custom-django-user-model/) and [tutorial-2](http://musings.tinbrain.net/blog/2014/sep/21/registration-django-easy-way/)).

This the model so far:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField('username', unique=True, db_index=True)
    joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

Now what I am confused about is that in [tutorial-1](http://blackglasses.me/2013/09/17/custom-django-user-model/), the author didn't made any custom manager for the custom User model. Instead he use forms for creating user.

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = 'Email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(), label = "Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(), label = 'Retype password')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean(self):
        """
        Verify that the values entered into the password fields match
        """
        cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise ValidationError("Password don't match.")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

But in [tutorial-2](http://musings.tinbrain.net/blog/2014/sep/21/registration-django-easy-way/), its author made a custom manager for the custom User model.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            is_active=True,
            **kwargs
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_staff=True,
            is_superuser=True,
            is_active=True,
            **kwargs
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Referencing with [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), there's an example of custom user model, and it uses custom manager. My question is, whether it is ok not to make any other custom manager and if not what is the use of creating a custom manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the relevant section from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) for you:

> You should also define a custom manager for your User model. If your User model defines `username`, `email`, `is_staff`, `is_active`, `is_superuser`, `last_login`, and `date_joined` fields the same as Django’s default `User`, you can just install Django’s `UserManager`; however, if your User model defines different fields, you will need to define a custom manager that extends `BaseUserManager` providing [the `create_user()` and `create_superuser()` methods].

The example in the docs needs to define a custom manager, so that it can set the `date_of_birth` field.

It appears that the example in the tutorial requires a custom manager, because it uses the `email` as the unique identifier, and does not have a separate username field.

Comment: Yes, that I got now, thank you. But I am still confused, because in tutorial-1, he is using `USERNAME_FIELD` as an email, but he didn't made another custom manager to handle that. Could you please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: If you [look at this comment](http://blackglasses.me/2013/09/17/custom-django-user-model/#comment-1527045990) on the first tutorial, it looks to me like it was a mistake to leave out the manager.

Comment: Ok. I think I am following now. Thank you so much for your help.