# What is the minimal setup for a Django Custom User Model?

Tags: django, django-custom-user, django-custom-manager

I would like to install, as recommended, a custom user model for a new project early in the process, to avoid complications in migrating further down the line.

But since the project is under development and acts as a testbed, I don't yet know which additional fields and methods I will require. I therefore want to get a custom user model up and running with the minimal required information so that the default registration (signup, login, etc) functions all work.

I used the following code, (in an app called 'accounts')

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and in `settings.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

I inherited from AbstractUser in order to obtain the default functionality, which seems to work.

However, the (default) signup produces the following error in the browser:

> Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'accounts.User'

So it seems to me that I must also define a UserManager for the custom User.

Now there is much advice available about how to do this if *additional* functionality is required (eg make the email the username, supply extra fields, and so on).

But at this stage, I don't want any additional functionality. That will come later. At this point I simply want to ensure that users can sign up, login, change passwords, etc and I can then develop the logic of the rest of the programme. I can return to the customization when I have developed this logic at which point it will be clear what additional functionality, if any, is required of the User model.

The problem is therefore (I think) to define a UserManager for my custom User Model.

So I tried the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
...
class User(AbstractUser):
    objects=UserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

This however returns the same error:

> Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'accounts.User'

Thus it seems I must also create a custom User Manager. Now, all the implementations I have seen require that such a user manager should inherit from BaseUserManager and implement at least `create_user` and `create_superuser`.

Is there some equivalent of 'AbstractUser' for the custom manager that allows me to simply get the default behaviour and customise later?

The nearest I've seen to a discussion of this matter is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033487/is-it-required-to-make-a-custom-manger-for-a-custom-user-model-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any references to the User model (from django.contrib.auth) in somewhere else in the code , make sure to update them to point to the custom user model from the accounts app. If you already have updated AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py, you can use:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that at present I have nowhere to put this code, because I'm invoking the default django signup. In the browser bar I simply enter

http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/

and this is when the fault appears.

I'

Comment: I'll check to see if there are any unnoticed references to the User model but I think there is only one, which reads:

```    
from capitalism.settings import AUTH_USER_MODEL
...
user=models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=None,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Update the line this way, also you probably don't need a custom manager for a simple AbstractUser for extra fields.

"""
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

user=models.ForeignKey(User,default=None,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
"""

Comment: If you want to keep the user reference from settings you might try using it this way.

"""
from django.conf import settings
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
"""